# Implementing round robin arbiter for PHP scripts

Tags: php, architecture

On my server, I have several PHP scripts running simultaneously that should use the same interface. They call the interface randomly.

That interface has limited "buses" it uses for the call. What I want to do is to add a round robin arbiter, that will direct each subsequent call to the next "bus".

I can do it with php and mysql. I can write a small program that stores the current round robin position, and when there is an interface call, it outputs that position, and increment the position in the database.

Since there are quite a lot of calls to that interface, I am thinking whether it is the most efficient way to do it. I feel that there must be a way to keep the program always running in the background in-memory, with the round robin as a variable. Mysql feels like an inefficient over kill. I might be wrong.

Some other options that I was thinking about are using java for the program and sockets to communicate with php, or using node.js

What do you think will be the most efficient solution for this arbiter?

Comment: use memcached? you could call http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.increment.php on each read to increase your counter easily

Comment: memcached seems like a great solution. I tried to install it, and it crashed my CentOS 6.6 server. I am battling for 4 hours now to recover. I don't know if I will make another attempt in the near future, but thanks for the idea

Comment: That's pretty weird. Sometimes it's tricky to install but I've never had any issues like that. Redis is an alternative

Comment: I don't know what happen, I had to rebuild apache to bring the server back up. I will take a look into redis after I recover from today's meltdown. Thanks

Comment: Finally got to install redis. Got it to work fairly easy, so thank you for that. As I am very new to nosql, any tips on how to generate my counter as a round-robin? or should I just let it be free running, and do the limiting on the application level?

Comment: yeah just increment the counter each time & in application, call the remainder function on the current counter's value by however many buses you want to use